# Plot a table with R

Tags: r, plot

I have the following `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("a","b","c","d"),
                 s1.pch = c(NA,5,5,5),
                 s1.col = c(NA,"red","green","yellow"),
                 s2.pch = c(3,3,3,3),
                 s2.col = c("blue","red","green","yellow"),
                 s3.pch = c(1,1,NA,1),
                 s4.col = c("blue","red",NA,"yellow"))
# df
#
#   id s1.pch s1.col s2.pch s2.col s3.pch s4.col
# 1  a     NA   <NA>      3   blue      1   blue
# 2  b      5    red      3    red      1    red
# 3  c      5  green      3  green     NA   <NA>
# 4  d      5 yellow      3 yellow      1 yellow
```

I want to plot it as a table, where row names are `df$id` and the column names are the s1, s2, s3 prefixes in `df`'s column names. The elements of the table are colored shapes where the shape is defined by the pch value in the columns ending with pch and the colors are defined by the columns ending with col.

This is what the figure should like for `df`.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could combine the parameters and define a custom function for the cells in gridExtra::tableGrob (I think it only works in the dev version)

[image]

```
library(grid)
# devtools::install_github('baptiste/gridextra')
library(gridExtra)
df <- data.frame(id = c("a","b","c","d"), 
                 s1.pch = c(NA,5,5,5), 
                 s1.col = c(NA,"red","green","yellow"), 
                 s2.pch = c(3,3,3,3), 
                 s2.col = c("blue","red","green","yellow"), 
                 s3.pch = c(1,1,NA,1), 
                 s3.col = c("blue","red",NA,"yellow"))

d <- data.frame(id=df$id, 
                s1 = paste(df$s1.col, df$s1.pch, sep=","),
                s2 = paste(df$s2.col, df$s2.pch, sep=","),
                s3 = paste(df$s3.col, df$s3.pch, sep=","))


my_fun <- function(label, ...){

  s <- strsplit(label, ",")[[1]]
  col <- s[1]
  pch <- ifelse(s[2]=="NA", NA, as.numeric(s[2]))

  pointsGrob(0.5,0.5,pch=pch, gp=gpar(col=col, lwd=3, cex=0.5))
}

tt <- ttheme_minimal(12, core=list(fg_fun = my_fun), 
                     rowhead=list(fg_params=list(fontface="bold")))

grid.newpage()
grid.table(d[,-1], rows=levels(d[,1]), theme = tt)
```

Comment: This looks very good but I can't get it to work - probably since I'm not using the dev version of gridExtra. Could you possibly add a link to where this can be downloaded from?

Comment: `devtools::install_github('baptiste/gridextra')`

Answer (score 3):

Here an option using `ggplot2`. It is nearly the desired output except the bold effect.

[image]

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
## reshape data
dd <- 
  melt(setDT(dat),id="id")[,c("var", "type"):=tstrsplit(variable,'[.]')][,variable:=NULL]
#" change factor order 
dd[,id:=factor(id,as.character(rev(unique(dd$id))))]


## extract shape scale
shape_scale <- unique(dd[type!="col"][!is.na(value),list(var,value)])
shape_scale <- setNames(as.numeric(shape_scale$value),shape_scale$var)
## color scale
cols <- unique(dd[type=="col" & !is.na(value),value])
col_scale <- setNames(cols,cols)
## plot
ggplot(dd[type!="pch"]) +
  geom_point(aes(x=var,y=id,label=value,shape=var,color=value),size=10) +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),  
        axis.title=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_text(size = 20))+
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_color_manual(values = col_scale) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shape_scale)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `ggplot` solution.

```
library(ggplot2)
gg.df     <- reshape(df,varying=list(c(2,4,6),c(3,5,7)),v.names=c("pch","col"),dir="long")
gg.df$id  <- factor(gg.df$id, levels=rev(levels(gg.df$id)))
ggplot(gg.df, aes(x=paste0("s",time),y=id)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=pch, color=col), size=5)+
  scale_color_identity()+
  scale_shape_identity()+
  labs(x=NULL,y=NULL)+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="black"),axis.text=element_text(size=20))
```

[image]

This is similar to the other answer except:

1. Uses `reshape(...)` in base R rather than data.table melt.
2. Takes advantage of `scale_shape_identity(...)` and
   `scale_color_identity(...)` rather than creating shape and color
   vectors.
3. I set the background to black just so the yellow is
   more apparent.